# Nougat get LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED action

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

As I read in documentation

[Direct Boot](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot) 
in Android N to receive action that boot was completed when device is locked we should use `android:directBootAware` and `android:encryptionAware` attributes in Manifest. Like this:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.BootCompletedReceiver"
    android:directBootAware="true"
    android:encryptionAware="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Unfortunately `android:encryptionAware` is marked as Unknown attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the documentation does not match between the English and Russian versions. The link you provided is for the Russian translation and only shows the use of `android:encryptionAware`. However, the English version only shows the use of `android:directBootAware`. Try using only `android:directBootAware`.